# Alternative isomorphism map to prove R-module isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

To prove $(R/I)\otimes_R M\cong M/IM$

($R$ a commutative ring with 1, $I$ an ideal in $R$, $M$ is an $R$-module.)

My professor's solution involves a map $f:(R/I)\otimes_R M\to M/IM$, with $f((r+I)\otimes m)=rm+IM$, with a solution that spans one page long.

My question, is can we have an alternative map as follows:

$g:(R/I)\otimes_R M\to M/IM$, with $g((1+I)\otimes m)=m+IM$.

My idea is that every element in the domain is of the form

$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^n ((r_i+I)\otimes m_i)&=\sum ((1+I)\otimes r_im_i)\\
&=(1+I)\otimes \sum r_im_i\\
&=(1+I)\otimes m
\end{aligned}$

for some $m\in M$.

Proving that $g$ is well-defined, homomorphism, bijective (through constructing an inverse) would certainly be neater and shorter than $f$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For any $a \in I$, $1 + a$ is another representative for $1 + I$.  Showing that a map is well-defined means exactly that it gives the same result for all representatives, and your map certainly is *not* "automatically" well-defined (although one can show that it is well-defined).  As user26857 said, the cleanest way to define a map out of a tensor product is to use its [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) by defining $R/I \times M \to M/IM$, $(r+I, m) \mapsto rm + IM$.

Comment: @SpamIAm Thanks. I am quite confused regarding well-definedness of tensor products. In undergrad, well-defined was mainly for coset representatives. I.e. If I defined a map $f:\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/2$ by $f(0+2\mathbb{Z})=0+2\mathbb{Z}$ and similarly for $f(1+2\mathbb{Z})=1+2\mathbb{Z}$, I believe that would be automatically well-defined, no? I wouldn't have to worry about $1+4$ and $1+6$ as two different representatives for $1+2\mathbb{Z}$? Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: Let $X$ be a set and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$.  If you want to define a function with domain $X/\sim$ by choosing a representative $x$ for each class $[x]$ and the defining $f$ by using this representative, you must show that if you pick a different representative $y$ for $[x]$, then using $f$ on this representative $y$ gives the same result.  This is what is meant by showing a map is *well-defined*.

Comment: Certainly the map you gave on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is well-defined since it is the identity, and since you defined the map without choosing representatives (mostly), I guess you don't really need to check that it's well-defined. But in your original question, you certainly do. Maybe a (wrong) example will show you why: Suppose I want to define a map $g: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $g((1+2\mathbb{Z}) \otimes m) = m$. Do you see why this map is not well-defined?  What is $g(1 + 2\mathbb{Z} \otimes 3)$?

Comment: @SpamIAm Ah I think I see it, the answer can be 3 or 1, so it is not well defined. Thanks for the enlightenment.